# how to connect to mongodb server via ssh tunnel with Proxy Jump (ProxyCommand)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh-tunnel, mongoose

I have an ssh config file like this.
I have a proxy jump to host1 from test2.

```
Host host1
  Hostname xxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
  Port 2222
  User xxxx
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  KeepAlive yes
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 30

Host test2
  Hostname xx.xxx.xx.xxx
  ProxyCommand  ssh.exe host1  -q -W %h:%p host1
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/cert
  KeepAlive yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 30
```

I have to Use SSH Tunneling to Mongodb using Host **test2**, But it uses Proxy Jump using **ProxyCommand**

I want to connect to mongodb using SSH Tunneling with a **Mongo DB Compass** and also with **node js mongoose**.

**How Can I connect using the Mongo DB Compass?**

[image]

Here I don't have an option to enter **ProxyCommand** details.

**How Can I connect using node js?**

I am using [tunnel-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel-ssh),  I have a reference code ,

```
var config = {
    username:'ubuntu',
    host:'xx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
    privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('~/.ssh/cert'),
    port:22,
    dstPort:27017,
    password:'mypassword'
};

var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
  
});
```

Here as well how can I enter **ProxyCommand** details here?